# Getting the current project directory from experimental instance of visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

I'm currently implementing uml validation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee329482.aspx,

when i debug, it opens a new experimental instance of visual studio for me to validate uml diagrams.

Is there a way to get the path of project directory selected by the user when the experimental instance of visual studio is running??

**To be more clear**,

project A - has VSIX and Class library components to validate uml validation. These class Library components are added to VSIX as MEF components

when i debug Project A -> new experimental instance of VS will open-> Then creating a new project (ctrl+shift+N)-> select modelling project-> browse to the directory (to store the modelling project)->Name the Project as "MYMODEL" -> then press OK

Now, In my Project A i need the path of MYMODEL. Can you please tell me how do i get that path??

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: What is an "experimental version of Visual Studio" and how did you get it?

Comment: install VisualStudio SDK and then: either create new project of type "vs (integration) package" and presss "debug", or check start menu for "vs sdk" group and there in tools you will find it. The ExerimentalInstance is simply "devenv.exe /rootsuffix Exp" what switches the IDE to use different, easily purgreable registry keys and file system folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit roundabout, but works.
You need references to EnvDTE and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0 as well as the usual bits.

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.Extensibility.Uml;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Modeling.Validation;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Uml.AuxiliaryConstructs;

namespace Validation
{
  public class MyValidationExtensions
  {
    [Import]
    public Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.SVsServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    [Export(typeof(System.Action<ValidationContext, object>))]
    [ValidationMethod(
     ValidationCategories.Open
     | ValidationCategories.Menu)]
    public void ValidateClassNames
      (ValidationContext context,
      // This type determines what elements 
      // will be validated by this method:
       IModel elementToValidate)
    {
      IModelStore store = elementToValidate.GetModelStore();
      EnvDTE.DTE dte = ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
      //dynamic projects = dte.ActiveSolutionProjects;

      foreach (EnvDTE.Project project in dte.Solution.Projects)
      {
        IModelingProject mp = project as IModelingProject;
        if (mp.Store == store)
        {
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(project.FullName);
        }
      }

    }
    // Add more validation methods for different element types.
  }
}
```